# How can I create standard layout for multiple pages?

Tags: html, css

Currently, I am working on my first web page using HTML and CSS. I want to use the same layout like background and header etc but I can't find a way. Today I found a couple of website telling about the template. Is this the related to what I want to do.

Thank you for helping a beginner.
Sam

Comment: This is just a workaround and may not be attractive to you, but if you develop using Visual Studio Express version.. by default there is a folder called `Shared`, and in that folder is an html page called `_Layout`.. and basically whatever HTML is on that page, that will show on each of your other pages unless you declare it not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you a few things:

- Find websites that make you feel as it is what you wanted to build.
- Check their source code and try to find the semantics they have maintained.
- Once you figured it out, you should try to create similar one.
- You should follow HTML5 specifications , as it will help you build solid foundation. while doing this you will also understand best practices.
- HTML or designing mostly depends on requirements. so you might not get one rule to follow, just invest time understanding some great works out there and practice alot.

In case you are very concern to layout, search for website layout images and you will get plenty of images having typical elements like header, navigation/menu, body (left/right sub menu + main content), footer.

You can consider templates for learning but it may lead you to trap of copying-pasting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Expression Web application, which handles template. You make one page and save it as template and declare editable parts for sites. Then You can create multiple empty HTML pages. Finally you attach template, then it works.

**Or**  if you can use PHP, you can create different parts of your Web Site, like: **header.php, footer.php, banner.php** and include them in every page where modifying the body and not writing the same footer, header, banner

Comment: Thanks so much, your suggestion were totally useful.

Comment: You are welcome )